# How to implement updates from mySQL operational DB to Azure SQL DB for reporting

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-data-factory

We have an **operational mySQL DB running on AWS** for a transactional system and an **Azure SQL DB for reporting** with PowerBI. Now I'd like to regularly (e.g. every night) do an update of certain tables from the mySQL DB to the Azure SQL DB.

I found [this description on how to do incremental copies using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview), however the alternatives don't seem feasible to me:

1. [Delta data loading from database by using a watermark](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) requires adding watermark columns to the source DB, but I don't want to make changes to the operational DB because it is managed and regularly updated by the transactional system.
2. [Delta data loading from SQL DB by using the Change Tracking technology](http://Delta%20data%20loading%20from%20database%20by%20using%20a%20watermark) seems to require an SQL Server DB as the source if I understand this correctly.

The remaining two alternatives apply only to updates from files, not DBs, to my understanding.

Are there other feasible alternatives based on the described conditions? They don't necessarily need to involve Azure Data Factory, however the updates should run completely automated in the cloud.

Maybe a non-incremental update (i.e. full replacement of the target DB tables every time) would be an option too, but I'm afraid that this would lead to high costs on the Azure SQL Server side - please share any experience on that as well, if available.

Comment: see also [same question on Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/237185/179589)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the watermark pattern as descibed, but have the watermark table in your destination database. You'll have to make sure that your lookup activity gets the watermark from the destination database instead of the source database.

I think the example puts the watermark table in the source because the destination is a blob-store. In your case, the destination is an Azure SQL db, so you can create  it in the destination db.

Whether a full load is a good option really depends on the requirements of your reports and amount of data that you'll need to move. Maybe you just need data from the last month? In that case you could create a where clause in your source query to filter only the last month and truncate the destionation table in the pre copy script of your copy activity.

Comment: I don't think putting the watermark column in the destination table would work. In the [detailed description](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-powershell) (which is also related to a target DB, not a BLOB storage), it says: _Select one column for each table in the source data store, which can be used to identify the new or updated records for every run. Normally, the data in this selected column (for example, last_modify_time or ID) keeps increasing when rows are created or updated._ In the destination table this would never change.

Comment: @Simon Zeinstra is right the destination watermark can change, you can just create a procedure to update the watermark from the last business key that was inserted in destination table.